# DEPRECATION WARNING: `#column_for_attribute` will return a null object for non-existent columns in Rails 5. Use `#has_attribute?`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I migrated my application from Rails 3.2 to 4.2.6. Whenever I run my application, this is the warning I am getting:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: `#column_for_attribute` will return a null object
>   for non-existent columns in Rails 5. Use `#has_attribute?` if you need
>   to check for an attribute's existence. (called from block (2 levels)
>   in _app_views_sessions_new_html_erb__912345678695999592_96040780 at
>   /home/myuser/Desktop/myproject/app/views/sessions/new.html.erb:12)

This is the form it is showing in the logs and the warning is at the password line:

```
<%= semantic_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_session_path, :remote => true, :format => :json}) do |f| %>
      <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :email, :label => 'Your email address', :input_html => { :placeholder => "Email"} %>
        <%= f.input :password, :label => 'Your password', :required => true, :input_html => { :placeholder => "Password"} %>
      <% end %>
       <%= f.submit_button :label => 'Sign me in', :button_html => {:class => 'login submit button', :id => 'user_submit' }%>
 <% end %>
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you using something else like Devise? If so you may need to upgrade that dependency as well.

Comment: I am using devise and I upgraded it to 4.2.0.

Comment: Next step is to check if Devise has an open issue for this. Since this is a Rails 5 warning that might be the case.

Answer (score 0):

The deprecation warning you're seeing has to do with Formtastic. Rails is noticing that you have some fields in your form (like a Password Confirmation field) that does not correspond to any field in your model.

This warning also happened to users of [Formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/issues/1117) and Simple Form between Rails 4.1 and 4.2 and was fixed with new releases of the specific product.

In the meantime, it's a deprecation warning, as opposed to an exception, so as annoying as it might be, it's not a showstopper.